# <Menu> throws "type is invalid" error ... no matter what I do

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm attempting to put together a generalized select menu using Material-UI's (1.0.0-beta.4) `<Button>`, `<Menu>`, and `<MenuItem>` components.

Inevitably it blows up on the use of `<Menu>` throwing:
`React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.`

As you can see, despite the error message, I'm clearly exporting the class. The error goes away if I remove the `<Menu>`, even if I leave the child `<MenuItem>` tags.

**Any idea what's going wrong? How to fix this??**

Here is the class:

```
class SelectMenu extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false,
            selectedIndex: 0
        };
        this.closeMenu = this.closeMenu.bind(this);
        this.openMenu = this.openMenu.bind(this);
        this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    }

    openMenu(event){
        this.setState({ open: true, anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
    }

    closeMenu(){
        this.setState({ open: false });
    }

    handleSelect(selectedValue, i){
        this.props.handleSelect(selectedValue);
        this.state.selectedIndex = i;
        this.closeMenu();
    };

    render(){ return (
        <div ref={el=>this.anchorEl=el}>
            <Button
              onClick={this.openMenu}
            >
            {this.props.children}
            </Button>
            <Menu
              id="simple-menu"
              anchorEl={this.props.anchorEl}
              open={this.state.open}
              onRequestClose={this.closeMenu}
            >
            {this.props.items.map((item,i) => 
                <MenuItem 
                    key={i}
                    selected={i === this.state.selectedIndex}
                    onClick={()=>(this.handleSelect(this.props.valueFor(item)))}
                >
                    {this.props.labelFor(item)}
                </MenuItem>
            )}
            </Menu>
        </div>
    )}
}

export default SelectMenu
```

Here's how I'm attempting to use it:

```
            <SelectMenu
                id="characterMenu"
                items={characters.array()}
                valueFor={((character)=>character.id)} 
                labelFor={((character)=>character.name)}
                handleSelect={(selectedValue)=>this.setState({
                    characterId: selectedValue
                })}
                anchorEl={this.menu}
                ref={(el)=>this.menu=el}
                >
                Choose Character
            </SelectMenu>
```

Comment: Where is the export happening? I'm not seeing it. Would expect something like `export default class SelectMenu extends...`

Comment: @ChristopherMesser, sorry -- the export statement must not have made it onto my clipboard. I just added it to that block of code in this post.

Comment: @Faust, Are you importing the Menu without curly braces?

Comment: @Andrew: `import { Menu, MenuItem } from 'material-ui/Menu';`

Comment: One error:  my onClick should be `{this.openMenu}`  (not `{this.open}`, I've corrected that, but it doesn't fix my bigger problem.

Comment: @Faust, have you tried import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem'; ?

Comment: @Andrew: Trying that, I get: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'material-ui/MenuItem' ` I was not previously getting any module errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

importing MenuItem using

```
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
```

worked for me.After that 
try to enclose your material ui components with

```
    import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

<MuiThemeProvider>
...
..
...
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: `Can't resolve 'material-ui/MenuItem' ` ... looks like they've re-arranged things in v1.0.0-beta.4. Now you have to get MenuItem from material-ui/Menu. *That* works. It's' Menu that doesn't work. The import doesn't fail, but the value of Menu is undefined.

Comment: It's complaining about a required `theme` prop. I'll try to figure that one out tomorrow.